# Fancybox trigger click with parameters

Tags: jquery, fancybox, eventtrigger

I need trigger click fancybox and send parameters to append into fancybox.

I triger and try pass params in this way:

```
var params = {};
$("#selector").trigger("click", params);
```

I can obtain params. But how can I append them to fancybox **.fancybox-iframe**? In click event is not .fancybox-iframe accessable.

```
$("#selector").fancybox({
            type: "iframe",
            width: "450",
            height: "430"},
}).click(function(event, params) {
  console.log(params);
});
```

Fancybox .fancybox-iframe is accessable like that:

```
$("#selector").fancybox({
  afterLoad: function(obj){
    console.log(obj.content);
  }
});
```

But there I haven't triggered params.

Do someone know simple workaround of this problem?

Comment: It seems like a common problem, I'm surprised that he never dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
$(document).on('click', '#selector', function(e, params) {
  $this = $(this);
  $.fancybox({
    height: '100%',
    href: $this.attr('href'),
    type: 'iframe',
    width: '100%',
    afterLoad: function(current) {
      current.content.contents().find('form').prepend(params);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```